# Error al crear clase .CS con xsd.exe en VisualStudio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Estoy creando una clase con la herramienta xsd.exe y al ejecutar el comando me sale el siguiente error : Schema validation warning  No se ha declarado el elemento 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:Signature'. Line 667, position 6.

Esta es la línea 667 del archivo

```
<xs:element ref="ds:Signature" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

Este es el encabezado del archivo xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns="https://tribunet.hacienda.go.cr/docs/esquemas/2017/v4.2/facturaElectronica" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" targetNamespace="https://tribunet.hacienda.go.cr/docs/esquemas/2017/v4.2/facturaElectronica" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="4.2" vc:minVersion="1.1">
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xmldsig-core-20080610/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
```

Apartir de esta linea es el error

```
<xs:element ref="ds:Signature" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="EmisorType">
```

Comment: Puedes agregar todo tu archivo

Comment: El Archivo es demasiado grande pero edite mi pregunta y agrege lineas a partir de donde marca el error en la linea 667

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la cabecera del archivo la definición `xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"` debe resolver a un ruta donde este el archivo XSD. Es decir tu ruta debe terminar con .xsd y ahí en esa ruta debe estar el archivo xsd que define el namespace ds. Por eso marca error porque en la ruta que tiene actualmente no existe el archivo XSD.

Answer (score 3):

si tienes el archivo `xmldsig-core-schema.xsd` añadelo al crear las clases con el xsd.

Algo así:

```
CMD-->  xsd TuDocumento.xsd xmldsig-core-schema.xsd /Classes
```

Comment: En los headers del Schema dice xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
y además  schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xmldsig-core-20080610/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd

Comment: @EfrainMejiasC, si por eso hay que añadírselo al XSD

Comment: CMD -- > xsd.exe MensajeHacienda_V4.2.xsd  xmldsig-core-schema.xsd /C /l:CS